# Donut texture painting : weird patterns appear

Tags: modeling, uv, texture-painting

Im currently in "Part 3, Level 2: Texture Painting" of the donut tutorial made by Blender Guru.

As I started painting the donut in "Texture Paint", weird patterns started appearing on my donut.

You can see the patterns in the screenshots below.

It seems like they appear when I paint close to the edge of the UV image.

The UV mapping looks wrong on one part as you can see on the last image.

Any idea what I did wrong and how I can solve this ?

I am using version 2.83.1

[image]

[image]

[image]

After doing the smart unwrap it looks like this :

[image]

Comment: Did you UV unwrap it properly? If not click U and unwrap or smart UV project it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After doing the smart UV project it looks like the picture above. It seems better but still not perfect ?

Comment: You have done it in the wrong way you should get a rectangle.This is how we can put it simply: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nr-UgnZLxvg. Also this will help you to unwrap a torus https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNRLDPrQAJU